# Hide component from any active component?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

There is a component `<app-tabs-components>`.

It gets data from service. There is variable `show: boolean` in this service to **show/hide** component on the page.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TabService {
    show = false;
    showHide(status: boolean) { 
        this.show = status;
    }

     get() {
          return this.show;
     }
}
```

Problem is that I need to call `tabService.showHide(false)` in every component where I want to hide component `<app-tabs-components>`.

Component `<app-tabs-components>` always should be closed if it lost focus, not active area.

In my case I am breaking DRY principle.

For example, when user activates any component I must do:

```
ngOnInit() {
  tabService.showHide(false)
}
```

So this part of code is repeated ine each component where I wan to hide tabsComponent

Comment: Can you post an example of your component code to demonstrate what your problem is. I don't understand what the problem is here.

Comment: Sure,see my updated question

Comment: Is `<app-tabs-components>` your component? Can you modify it?

Comment: Yes, I just hide this compoent when I DONT USE IT, for exampl I actiavate another component

Comment: So why don't you just inject the service into that component? The question still doesn't contain enough information to demonstrate the problem you are having.

Comment: Beause I have a lot of components where I should iject service to show/hide. It is DRY for one line of code

Comment: Please post the `<app-tabs-components>` code and usages in other components

Comment: Done, see question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Base Class and in constructor of this class call the your service.

```
export class BaseComp  {

  public IsHide: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.IsHide = tabService.showHide(false);
  }

}
```

Inherit this BaseComp in different Components.

```
export class YourComponent extends BaseComp implements OnInit  {

constructor() {
  super(); // calls the base constructor 
  console.log(this.IsHide); // this IsHide is of Base class
}

ngOnInit() {

}

}
```

Hope this helps !!